# reledmac linenumbers inside of the print space

Tags: line-numbering, reledmac, linenumber

Using the `reledmac` package I have trouble with putting the linenumbers inside of the print space (cf. picture).

[image]

The code in the preamble is now simply:

```
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\usepackage[series={A,B,C}]{reledmac}
\usepackage{reledpar}


%%%\Xendnumberonlyfirstinline
\Xendbeforepagenumber{S.\,}
\Xendafterpagenumber{:\,}
\Xendlineprefixsingle{Z.\,}

\setgoalfraction{0.85}

\usepackage{url}
\urlstyle{same}

\lineation{section}
\linenummargin{left}%%right für Zeilennummern rechts
%%%\setRlineflag{}


\usepackage{pdflscape} %%Querformatiges Bild

\linenumincrement*{5}
\firstlinenum*{0} %Zahl hochsetzen, um Titelei unnummeriert zu haben
```

How can I get the linenumber inside of the document?

A "minimal" Example with the full preamble:

```
% arara: xelatex

\documentclass[10pt,twoside]{scrbook}
\KOMAoptions
  {
    fontsize=10pt,
    paper=24cm:17cm,
    pagesize=pdftex,
    DIV=calc,
  } %%%weitere Einstellungen des Seitenspiegels



  \usepackage{leading}
  \leading{12pt}




  \usepackage[%%%text={12cm,17.8cm},
paperwidth=17cm,
paperheight=23cm,
    top=1.6cm,%%%3.45cm,
    bottom=3.45cm,%%%8.04cm,
    inner=2.7cm,%%%4.15cm,
    outer=2.3cm,%%%4.85cm,
   %%% marginparsep=7mm,
    %%%marginparwidth=48mm,
  ]{geometry} %%% Seitenlayout 

%%\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}

%%\usepackage[bmargin=2.25cm]{geometry}


%%\setheadsepline{0.4pt}
\setkomafont{pageheadfoot}{\normalfont\normalcolor\small}\setkomafont{pagenumber}{\normalfont}

%Formatierung der Kopfzeilen:
\addtokomafont{pagehead}{\normalfont}


\setkomafont{disposition}{\normalcolor\bfseries} %Schrift in Überschriften, Inhaltsverzeichnis

\clubpenalty=10000
\widowpenalty=10000

\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\usepackage[series={A,B,C}]{reledmac}
\usepackage{reledpar}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{epigraph} %für Zitate

\usepackage{tipa} %%für IPA-Zeichen
%%%\Xendnumberonlyfirstinline

\Xendbeforepagenumber{S.\,}
\Xendafterpagenumber{:\,}
\Xendlineprefixsingle{Z.\,}

\setgoalfraction{0.85}

\usepackage{url}
\urlstyle{same}

\lineation{section}
\linenummargin{left}%%right für Zeilennummern rechts
%\setRlineflag{}


\usepackage{pdflscape} %%Querformatiges Bild

\linenumincrement*{5}
\firstlinenum*{0} %Zahl hochsetzen, um Titelei unnummeriert zu haben

\maxchunks{10000}

% Hurenkinder und Schusterjungen verhindern
\clubpenalty10000
\widowpenalty10000
\displaywidowpenalty=10000

\usepackage{tabularx}

\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{multicol,multirow, bigdelim}%%times RAUS
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia, xunicode}
\usepackage{libertine}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Linux Libertine}%Linux Libertine O %%EzraSIL hat keine kursiva

\let\svthefootnote\thefootnote %idee wegen fußnotenabstand

\setmainlanguage{german} 
\setotherlanguage{hebrew}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Script=Hebrew, Scale=0.8]{EzraSIL} %Keter YG %%hebräische schrift auf 9ppt verkleinert



%addsubsection definiert
\makeatletter
\newcommand*\addsubsec{\secdef\@addsubsec\@saddsubsec}
\newcommand*{\@addsubsec}{}
\def\@addsubsec[#1]#2{\subsection*{#2}\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{#1}
  \if@twoside\ifx\@mkboth\markboth\markright{#1}\fi\fi
}
\newcommand*{\@saddsubsec}[1]{\subsection*{#1}\@mkboth{}{}}
\makeatother




%Header
\usepackage[automark]{scrpage2}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\clearscrheadfoot
\chead{\headmark}
\ohead{\pagemark}
\automark[section]{chapter}
\renewcommand*{\sectionmarkformat}{}
\renewcommand*{\chaptermarkformat}{}


\setmainlanguage{german}
\setotherlanguage{hebrew}




\newcommand\einzugjid{\hangindent=5mm\hangafter=1}

\newcommand\speaker[1]{\noindent{#1} \einzugjid
}

\newcommand\einzug{\hangindent=5mm\hangafter=1}

\newcommand\speakerd[1]{\noindent
{\textsc{#1}} \einzug
}


\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}



\usepackage[german=guillemets]{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=authoryear,language=ngerman]{biblatex} \bibliography{LitGrobsdorfEdition}
\renewcommand*{\postnotedelim}{\addcolon\,}
\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{multipostnote}{#1}


\deffootnote[\normalparindent]
            {0em}
            {\normalparindent}
            {\thefootnotemark\ \,}
\newlength{\normalparindent}
\AtBeginDocument{\setlength{\normalparindent}{\parindent}}

\usepackage{bidi}\autofootnoterule

\deffootnote{1em}{0em}{\thefootnotemark\ \,} %%neu aus Ricarda-Diss



\wrapcontentX[A]{\texthebrew}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\footnoteruleA}{\right@footnoterule}
\makeatother



\usepackage{gb4e}
\noautomath

\begin{document}




\begin{pages}
\begin{Leftside}\begin{hebrew}
 \setRTL
 \beginnumbering

\pstart {\large{{\texthebrew{\textbf{איילפטער אויפטריטט}}}}}  \pend
\pstart {\texthebrew{גומפלכען אלליין}}   \pend




\pstart {\texthebrew{
 איך בין דאָך גאָטטלויב בייא דיע מערערכער רעכט אַהגעזֵיעה –. זיע האָן מיך מיינע שמה אַלל גערן. דוא איס אַזוֹא אַהנע הויזע פֿון {שמאַלשטאַדט}, דיע לאָסט דאָך אַס חַזֶר קאַהן אַהג פֿוממער. דוֹא ווילל איך אַה שבועה דרוף טהוא, דאַס דיע פֿערליבט אין מיר איס. דען ווען איך איהר אַביסכה שפאַס מאַכע ווילל, דען גֵיהט זיע גלייך
{{\begin{small}|\liningnums{35}|\end{small}}}
 פֿאָרט, אַלס ווען זיע ניקס צו טוא וועלט מיט מיר האָן; און דאַס איס דער רעכטע סימן, דאַס זיע פֿערליעבט אין מיר איס. יאַ גומפלכה איס קאַה שוטה! – יאַ, יאַ, אום {בחינים} גֵיהט זיע מיר ניט איממער אויס דעם וועג, וואו זיע מיך זיכט. – איך בין אָבער אַהך אַה ראַהר קערלכע. זאָלל מיך אַה דוננער פערשלאַגע (זיעהט אין דען שפיעגעל) אַה בֵיזעל בין איך! אַה ביסכה דיקקער זעללט איך זייא. נוא, וואַס טוט מער דערמיט. דער מענש מאַכט זיך ניט זעלבסט. איך ווארד ערשט נאך אַמויהל אין   דען הויף גאַנגע,
  דען קאממער בעססער בייא זיך פאַקקע.  יאַ, גומפלכה איס קאַה שוטה.
איך בין מיינע שמה געשייטער וויע זיע אַלל, זיע
 {אוצע}
  מיך אָסר אלל ניט.
}} \pend
%%ed \footnotetextB[\ref{ric1}]{{\texthebrew{אוצע}}: \LR{‘foppen’, \parencite[§\,309]{Tendlau1860} \textit{uzen},  \parencite[43]{GuggenheimGruenberg1976} \textit{uuzəә}, hessisch \textit{uzen}, \textit{utzen} \parencite[281]{Hessen-NassauischesWB}.}}



  \pstart  {\texthebrew{ענדע דעס ערשטן אופצוגס.{\begin{small}|\liningnums{36}|\end{small}}
}}   \pend


     \endnumbering
\end{hebrew}\end{Leftside}


\begin{Rightside}

\beginnumbering

\pstart {\large \textbf{Elfter Auftritt}} \pend
\pstart  \textit{Gumpelchen alleine} \pend


\pstart  Ich bin doch gottlob bei den Mädchen recht angesehen. – Sie haben mich alle gern. Da ist so eine aus Schmalstadt, die kann nicht von mir lassen. Da will ich drauf schwören, dass die verliebt in mich ist. Denn wenn ich mit ihr ein bisschen Spaß machen will, dann geht sie gleich fort, als ob sie nichts mit mir zu tun haben wollte; und das ist das rechte Anzeichen, dass sie in mich verliebt ist. Ja, Gumpelchen ist kein Narr! Ja, ja, sie geht mir ja nicht umsonst immer aus dem Weg, wenn sie mich sieht. Ich bin aber auch ein toller Kerl, soll mich der Donner erschlagen. \textit{(Sieht in den Spiegel.)} Ah, ein schöner Mann bin ich. Ein bisschen dicker sollte ich sein. Nun, was tut man dann. Der Mensch macht sich nicht selbst. Ich werde erst noch einmal in den Hof gehen, dann kann man mehr zu sich packen. Ja, Gumpelchen ist kein Narr. Ich bin, meine Seele, gescheiter wie sie alle, sie foppen mich gewiss alle nicht. \pend

\pstart Ende des ersten Aufzugs. \pend

\endnumbering

\end{Rightside}
\end{pages}
\Pages

\end{document}
```

Comment: Your example is not really minimal and does not compile (mainly because of the fonts). Could you try to throw out all the stuff that is not strictly necessary for this problem?

Comment: If I remove some of the stuff concerning the fonts I can compile your example. What I can see is that the page number and the line numbers don't align. If you want to fix that, you should move the the page number in the margin and (if needed) make the text narrower. Is this what you want?

Comment: thanks! that is exactly what I want. But how do I "move the the page number in the margin "?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the depreciated package `scrpage2`, it has been replaced by `scrlayer-scrpage`, which allows you to define layers in the margin, which can contain the page number:

```
\DeclareNewLayer[
  oddpage,
  rightmargin,
  height=1in+\voffset+\topmargin+\headheight,
  contents={\usekomafont{pageheadfoot}\usekomafont{pagehead}%
    \vfill%
    \hspace{\marginparsep}\pagemark\hfill%
  }
]{pagenumber.odd}

\DeclareNewLayer[
  evenpage,
  leftmargin,
  height=1in+\voffset+\topmargin+\headheight,
  contents={\usekomafont{pageheadfoot}\usekomafont{pagehead}%
    \vfill% 
    \hfill\pagemark\hspace{\marginparsep}%
  }
]{pagenumber.even}

\AddLayersToPageStyle{scrheadings}{pagenumber.odd, pagenumber.even}
```

When you embed this in your document like that:

```
% arara: xelatex

\documentclass[10pt,twoside]{scrbook}
\KOMAoptions
  {
    fontsize=10pt,
    paper=24cm:17cm,
    pagesize=pdftex,
    DIV=calc,
  } %%%weitere Einstellungen des Seitenspiegels



  \usepackage{leading}
  \leading{12pt}




  \usepackage[%%%text={12cm,17.8cm},
paperwidth=17cm,
paperheight=23cm,
    top=1.6cm,%%%3.45cm,
    bottom=3.45cm,%%%8.04cm,
    inner=2.7cm,%%%4.15cm,
    outer=2.3cm,%%%4.85cm,
   %%% marginparsep=7mm,
    %%%marginparwidth=48mm,
  ]{geometry} %%% Seitenlayout 

%%\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}

%%\usepackage[bmargin=2.25cm]{geometry}


%%\setheadsepline{0.4pt}
\setkomafont{pageheadfoot}{\normalfont\normalcolor\small}\setkomafont{pagenumber}{\normalfont}

%Formatierung der Kopfzeilen:
\addtokomafont{pagehead}{\normalfont}


\setkomafont{disposition}{\normalcolor\bfseries} %Schrift in Überschriften, Inhaltsverzeichnis

\clubpenalty=10000
\widowpenalty=10000

\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\usepackage[series={A,B,C}]{reledmac}
\usepackage{reledpar}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{epigraph} %für Zitate

\usepackage{tipa} %%für IPA-Zeichen
%%%\Xendnumberonlyfirstinline

\Xendbeforepagenumber{S.\,}
\Xendafterpagenumber{:\,}
\Xendlineprefixsingle{Z.\,}

\setgoalfraction{0.85}

\usepackage{url}
\urlstyle{same}

\lineation{section}
\linenummargin{left}%%right für Zeilennummern rechts
%\setRlineflag{}


\usepackage{pdflscape} %%Querformatiges Bild

\linenumincrement*{5}
\firstlinenum*{0} %Zahl hochsetzen, um Titelei unnummeriert zu haben

\maxchunks{10000}

% Hurenkinder und Schusterjungen verhindern
\clubpenalty10000
\widowpenalty10000
\displaywidowpenalty=10000

\usepackage{tabularx}

\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{multicol,multirow, bigdelim}%%times RAUS
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia, xunicode}
\usepackage{libertine}
% \setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Linux Libertine}%Linux Libertine O %%EzraSIL hat keine kursiva

\let\svthefootnote\thefootnote %idee wegen fußnotenabstand

\setmainlanguage{german} 
\setotherlanguage{hebrew}
% \newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Script=Hebrew, Scale=0.8]{EzraSIL} %Keter YG %%hebräische schrift auf 9ppt verkleinert



%addsubsection definiert
\makeatletter
\newcommand*\addsubsec{\secdef\@addsubsec\@saddsubsec}
\newcommand*{\@addsubsec}{}
\def\@addsubsec[#1]#2{\subsection*{#2}\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{#1}
  \if@twoside\ifx\@mkboth\markboth\markright{#1}\fi\fi
}
\newcommand*{\@saddsubsec}[1]{\subsection*{#1}\@mkboth{}{}}
\makeatother




%Header
\usepackage[automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}

\DeclareNewLayer[
  oddpage,
  rightmargin,
  height=1in+\voffset+\topmargin+\headheight,
  contents={\usekomafont{pageheadfoot}\usekomafont{pagehead}%
    \vfill%
    \hspace{\marginparsep}\pagemark\hfill%
  }
]{pagenumber.odd}

\DeclareNewLayer[
  evenpage,
  leftmargin,
  height=1in+\voffset+\topmargin+\headheight,
  contents={\usekomafont{pageheadfoot}\usekomafont{pagehead}%
    \vfill% 
    \hfill\pagemark\hspace{\marginparsep}%
  }
]{pagenumber.even}

\AddLayersToPageStyle{scrheadings}{pagenumber.odd, pagenumber.even}

\clearscrheadfoot
\chead{\headmark}
\automark[section]{chapter}
\renewcommand*{\sectionmarkformat}{}
\renewcommand*{\chaptermarkformat}{}


\setmainlanguage{german}
\setotherlanguage{hebrew}




\newcommand\einzugjid{\hangindent=5mm\hangafter=1}

\newcommand\speaker[1]{\noindent{#1} \einzugjid
}

\newcommand\einzug{\hangindent=5mm\hangafter=1}

\newcommand\speakerd[1]{\noindent
{\textsc{#1}} \einzug
}


\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}



\usepackage[german=guillemets]{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=authoryear,language=ngerman]{biblatex} \bibliography{LitGrobsdorfEdition}
\renewcommand*{\postnotedelim}{\addcolon\,}
\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{multipostnote}{#1}


\deffootnote[\normalparindent]
            {0em}
            {\normalparindent}
            {\thefootnotemark\ \,}
\newlength{\normalparindent}
\AtBeginDocument{\setlength{\normalparindent}{\parindent}}

\usepackage{bidi}\autofootnoterule

\deffootnote{1em}{0em}{\thefootnotemark\ \,} %%neu aus Ricarda-Diss



\wrapcontentX[A]{\texthebrew}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\footnoteruleA}{\right@footnoterule}
\makeatother



\usepackage{gb4e}
\noautomath

\begin{document}




\begin{pages}
\begin{Leftside}\begin{hebrew}
 \setRTL
 \beginnumbering

\pstart {\large{{\texthebrew{\textbf{איילפטער אויפטריטט}}}}}  \pend
\pstart {\texthebrew{גומפלכען אלליין}}   \pend




\pstart {\texthebrew{
 איך בין דאָך גאָטטלויב בייא דיע מערערכער רעכט אַהגעזֵיעה –. זיע האָן מיך מיינע שמה אַלל גערן. דוא איס אַזוֹא אַהנע הויזע פֿון {שמאַלשטאַדט}, דיע לאָסט דאָך אַס חַזֶר קאַהן אַהג פֿוממער. דוֹא ווילל איך אַה שבועה דרוף טהוא, דאַס דיע פֿערליבט אין מיר איס. דען ווען איך איהר אַביסכה שפאַס מאַכע ווילל, דען גֵיהט זיע גלייך
{{\begin{small}|\liningnums{35}|\end{small}}}
 פֿאָרט, אַלס ווען זיע ניקס צו טוא וועלט מיט מיר האָן; און דאַס איס דער רעכטע סימן, דאַס זיע פֿערליעבט אין מיר איס. יאַ גומפלכה איס קאַה שוטה! – יאַ, יאַ, אום {בחינים} גֵיהט זיע מיר ניט איממער אויס דעם וועג, וואו זיע מיך זיכט. – איך בין אָבער אַהך אַה ראַהר קערלכע. זאָלל מיך אַה דוננער פערשלאַגע (זיעהט אין דען שפיעגעל) אַה בֵיזעל בין איך! אַה ביסכה דיקקער זעללט איך זייא. נוא, וואַס טוט מער דערמיט. דער מענש מאַכט זיך ניט זעלבסט. איך ווארד ערשט נאך אַמויהל אין   דען הויף גאַנגע,
  דען קאממער בעססער בייא זיך פאַקקע.  יאַ, גומפלכה איס קאַה שוטה.
איך בין מיינע שמה געשייטער וויע זיע אַלל, זיע
 {אוצע}
  מיך אָסר אלל ניט.
}} \pend
%%ed \footnotetextB[\ref{ric1}]{{\texthebrew{אוצע}}: \LR{‘foppen’, \parencite[§\,309]{Tendlau1860} \textit{uzen},  \parencite[43]{GuggenheimGruenberg1976} \textit{uuzəә}, hessisch \textit{uzen}, \textit{utzen} \parencite[281]{Hessen-NassauischesWB}.}}



  \pstart  {\texthebrew{ענדע דעס ערשטן אופצוגס.{\begin{small}|\liningnums{36}|\end{small}}
}}   \pend


     \endnumbering
\end{hebrew}\end{Leftside}


\begin{Rightside}

\beginnumbering

\pstart {\large \textbf{Elfter Auftritt}} \pend
\pstart  \textit{Gumpelchen alleine} \pend


\pstart  Ich bin doch gottlob bei den Mädchen recht angesehen. – Sie haben mich alle gern. Da ist so eine aus Schmalstadt, die kann nicht von mir lassen. Da will ich drauf schwören, dass die verliebt in mich ist. Denn wenn ich mit ihr ein bisschen Spaß machen will, dann geht sie gleich fort, als ob sie nichts mit mir zu tun haben wollte; und das ist das rechte Anzeichen, dass sie in mich verliebt ist. Ja, Gumpelchen ist kein Narr! Ja, ja, sie geht mir ja nicht umsonst immer aus dem Weg, wenn sie mich sieht. Ich bin aber auch ein toller Kerl, soll mich der Donner erschlagen. \textit{(Sieht in den Spiegel.)} Ah, ein schöner Mann bin ich. Ein bisschen dicker sollte ich sein. Nun, was tut man dann. Der Mensch macht sich nicht selbst. Ich werde erst noch einmal in den Hof gehen, dann kann man mehr zu sich packen. Ja, Gumpelchen ist kein Narr. Ich bin, meine Seele, gescheiter wie sie alle, sie foppen mich gewiss alle nicht. \pend

\pstart Ende des ersten Aufzugs. \pend

\endnumbering

\end{Rightside}
\end{pages}
\Pages

\end{document}
```

You will get page numbers in the margins:

[image]

Comment: Wow, thank you! It works – but with one strange problem: I only have the page-numbers for the right side but not for the left. Is there something missing?

Comment: I know it's a mess …has it's history. But thanks again. I'll try to get it work for the left pages…

Comment: Have a look at your original document, are you redefining the head somewhere else?

Comment: I have the problem even with your example above – as far as I see it, there is no other definition of the header

Comment: Strange. If you compile my example you get the page number 3 but not 2? Which TeX distribution are you using? Is it up to date?

Comment: it was an old reladmac package. sorry and thanks again!!!